# How to create a function that alloccate 10 bytes to a pointer, then check whether pointer has been allocated yet, return boolean?

Tags: c, function, pointers, boolean, definition

sorry for my bad English. I'm learning C programming from the root at the moment, and I have a homework.

The problem says: Create a function that allocate 10 bytes dynamically to a pointer, then check whether pointer has been allocated? The function must be a boolean one, and return boolean as well.

Function prototype: bool allocate10Bytes(uint8_t * outPtr);

Please help me on this. Thanks alot!

Comment: This is pretty much a wrapper for `malloc`.

Comment: The type of `outPtr` seems wrong, shouldn't it be `uint8_t **outPtr`?

Comment: The signature for your function should be `bool allocate10Bytes(uint8_t ** outPtr);`. It should be a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: @Ctx About the prototype, this is what I got from my mentor, and he said under no curcumstance, I do not have the right to change it.

Comment: Does your mentor also provide some hint how the allocated memory might be accessed outside that function?

Comment: Then this function will be a useless function to leak memory...

Comment: @phongisntreal We can't help if the question doesn't match the prototype.

Comment: What does "The function must be a boolean one, and return boolean as well." ? What does "be a boolean one" mean other than returning boolean?

Comment: I will email to my mentor for futher infos. And now assume that the prototype are ... ** outPtr, how can i solve this? Thanks!

Comment: *About the prototype, this is what I got from my mentor, and he said under no curcumstance, I do not have the right to change it.*  Assuming there's no mistake, your "mentor" is not qualified to be a mentor in C if he thinks that  the prototype he provided can work.

Comment: @Gerhardh As the prototype says, i need to make a bool function, and the returning values must be true or false, based on the pointer has been allocated or not. And he said he just need the function, not the entire program.

Comment: The easiest to understand thing that `allocate10Bytes` should do is something like: `*outPtr = malloc(10);` `return (*outPtr != NULL);`. A minimalist approach (which would make your mentor suspicious) is `return *outPtr = malloc(10);`

Comment: if you must use this signature you can redefine the type of uint8_t to be a pointer to unsigned char.  `typedef unsigned char* uint8_t;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you mean something like the following

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>

bool allocate10Bytes( uint8_t **outPtr )
{
    const size_t N = 10;

    *outPtr = malloc( N * sizeof( uint8_t ) );

    return *outPtr != NULL;
}

int main(void) 
{
    uint8_t *p;

    bool success = allocate10Bytes( &p );

    if ( success ) free( p );

    return 0;
}
```

This function prototype in your question

```
bool allocate10Bytes(uint8_t * outPtr);
```

is invalid. To be an out parameter the pointer must be declared as `uint8_t **outPtr`. That is an argument (some pointer) shall be passed by reference through a pointer to the pointer.

**Note**: If you are trying to compile the program as a C++ program then at least rewrite this statement

```
*outPtr = malloc( N * sizeof( uint8_t ) );
```

like

```
*outPtr = ( uint8_t * )malloc( N * sizeof( uint8_t ) );
```

and remove the header `<stdbool.h>`

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I have problem testing this program. I'm currently using DevC++ (as my mentor required) and the problem said: [Error] invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'uint8_t* {aka unsigned char*}' [-fpermissive] in the line *outPtr = malloc( N * sizeof( uint8_t ) );. Could you tell me more about it?

Comment: @phongisntreal I know nothing about what code you are running. I answered your question. If you have some problems with your code then ask a new question.

Comment: @phongisntreal: That is a C++ error message. You are compiling this code using a C++ compiler, but you tagged the question C. Which language do you want to use?

Comment: @phongisntreal You can write the call of malloc the following way *outPtr = ( uint8_t * )malloc( N * ( sizeof( uint8_t ) ); In this case the program will compile using a C++ compiler.

Comment: I need it in C and I will try it with gcc build in complier. Sorry for my immature programming skill :(

Comment: @phongisntreal As a C program it is valid and should compile. If the error you referenced to appears then it means that you are compiling the program as a C++ program.

Comment: @phongisntreal You can use the online compiler at www.ideone.com selecting the language tag as C99.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Really appriciate what you did here. I will dig into this and improve my programming skill.